# how useful is metaprogramming for building website with ruby on rails or django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I started learning ruby on rails few weeks ago. I don't completely understand metaprogramming yet, but first I want to ask whether metaprogramming is worth learning if I only want to use ruby on rails to build websites. The example I see for metaprogramming is for generating undefined class method on the fly, but is it necessary?

My background: I use python on a daily base for scientific computing and have limited experience with django.

Comment: This isn't really a concrete question, and is thus something that this site frowns upon. Is there a way you could rephrase it to something more specific?

Comment: Why do you mention python, and tag django, are you considering django as an alternative to RoR?

Comment: @JoshuaRieken I just want to know the how useful the metaprogramming is, I don't know any more specific question.

Comment: @cheeseweasel I mention python/django just for comparison of these two frameworks, as I come from python background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaprogramming is by no means a requirement to writing websites.

If you're beginning to program in Ruby, it's probably best not to worry about it until you're much more familiar with the language. The added flexibility it affords you comes at the expense of complexity and obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the functionality of the website. Learn the basic idea of meta programming , then carry on with what you're doing. You'll then know if you are trying to solve something that meta programming would help with, and you can dig in more.